# Submit Multi-Dimensional Array to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a mySQL table with the fields:

- preview_url
- large_url

And I have an object that I submit with the following structure:

```
var $urls = {largeImg:[],preview:[]}
```

$urls.largeImg values have to be inserted into 'large_url' and

$urls.preview_url values have to be inserted into 'preview_url'

$urls.largeImg[0] has to go in the same mysql table row as $urls.preview[0],

$urls.largeImg[1] into the same row as $urls.preview[1] and so on.

my php:

```
$urls = $_POST['urls'];

function cache_urls($urls){
global $db;


foreach($urls as $url){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cache ";
    $sql .= "(preview_url, large_url) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $url['preview']) . "', ";
    $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $url['largeImg']) . "'";
    $sql .= ");";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
```

And then I also tried this:

```
foreach($urls as $url){
    foreach($url as $key => $value){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cache ";
        $sql .= "(preview_url, large_url) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES (";
        if($key==="preview"){
            $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $value) . "', ";
        }
        if($key==="largeImg"){
            $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $value) . "'";
        }

        $sql .= ");";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    }       
}
```

So I assume the SQL bit must be wrong but I'm really at the end of my knowledge! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to echo $sql?

Comment: do you mean $sql or $result?

Comment: your $sql query string

Comment: I am not getting anything back, I am submitting this with ajax (jQuery). I tried to return $sql but I get nothing back.

Comment: well, try this echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(" + $sql + ")</script>";

Comment: Where would I echo this? I'm sorry, I'm really lost.

Comment: before $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

Comment: It's submitted with jQuery and AJAX so I can't see what I echo in php

Comment: Your code is probably vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks Dharman, yes I just removed everything that was irrelevant for this question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this way,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cache (preview_url, large_url) values";
foreach($urls["largeImg"] as $index => $large_url){
    $preview_url = $urls["preview"][$index];
    $sql .= "('" . db_escape($db,$preview_url) . "','" . db_escape($db,$large_url) . "'),";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. i get this error back: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/30/15/10/pizza-2802332_150.jpg''https://pi' at line 1

Comment: the url above in the error message is the second value from the array urls.preview (urls.preview[1]) if that helps?

Comment: @Melvin can you show you sql and error with text, not an image here.

Comment: that's the error message i get back, including the image url.

Comment: what's the value of `sql`

Comment: INSERT INTO cache (preview_url, large_img_url) VALUES('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/22/02/56/pizza-329523_150.jpg''https://pixabay.com/get/55e2dc464851b108f5d084609629347b143bd9ed514c704c732872d39f49c45d_1280.jpg''),('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/30/15/10/pizza-2802332_150.jpg''https://pixabay.com/get/54e8d5414951ae14f6da8c7dda79367d103edae25b536c4870297cdd9045c159bd_1280.jpg''),('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/10/57/pizza-2068272_150.jpg''https://pixabay.com/get/54e0d34b4855ae14f6da8c7dda79367d103edae25b536c4870297cdd9045c159bd_1280.jpg'')

Comment: @Melvin can you wrap your sql in code, I cannot see the full sql here.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know how to do that in a comment

Comment: `INSERT INTO pixa_cache (preview_url, large_img_url) `VALUES('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/22/02/56/pizza-`329523_150.jpg''https://pixabay.com/get/55e2dc464851b108f5d084609629347b``143bd9ed514c704c732872d39f49c45d_1280.jpg''),`('https://cdn.pixabay.com/ph`oto/2017/09/30/15/10/pizza-`2802332_150.jpg''https://pixabay.com/get/54e8d5414951ae14f6da8c7dda79367`d103edae25b536c4870297cdd9045c159bd_1280.jpg''),`('https://cdn.pixabay.com`/photo/2017/02/15/10/57/pizza-`2068272_150.jpg''https://pixabay.com/get/54e0d34b4855ae14f6da8c7dda79367`d103edae25b536c4870297cdd9045c159bd_1280.jpg'')

Comment: It's very clear, there missed a `,` in the sql. I edited it.

Comment: there's additional single quote at end, other than this, everything should be ok

Comment: Brilliant! Also there's one too many of these: ' at the end (I'm not sure if that has an influence), however I changed it to this (including your edit):
` $sql .= "('" . db_escape($db,$preview_url) . "','" . db_escape($db,$large_url) . "'),";
works perfectly now, thanks so much!